# Is there a way to check internal method variables with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i'm using Rspec for testing. I'm currently creating a combat system and i would need to test it as extensively as needed.

Till now, using rspec, i mostly check the outcome of a method on whether it should return a certain value, create certain records and so on.

But how can i actually(if possible) check a variable inside a method ? Think of this example :

```
def combat 
  weapon_damage = 30
  total_damage = weapon_damage + other_damage
  total_damage
end
```

How can i check the weapon_damage was 30, for example ? Or the value of other_damage ? As you see, i'm looking for a way to test the in between steps of my methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can not do that. In your case, I would suggest, you separate the call into multiple methods so you can test their outcome one by one. In general, if you tend to ask yourself what your methods are actually doing, it's a good sign that you should separate the code into multiple methods.

Comment: that's a good point for sure, but sometimes it's a bit too much to have methods for every little thing. But i see the point.

Comment: It's a great point. If it matters enough for you to want to check it, it's important enough to have in a separate method

Comment: I still think it would be cool to check inside method variables. I know you can with IDE's such as [Ruby Mine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), so it could have some application in Rspec. It would make your specs huge, but such a suite would be pretty darn watertight. Ah well, probably ultimately unnecessary